# Draw circles around main circle in JavaScript with draw2d

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, draw2d-js

In my application, I can draw circles with draw2d.js
I'd like to know how I can draw circles around a main circle (here is lightblue).

I'd like to make it dynamically, because I could have more than 200 circles, so I need to calculate coords compared to the main circle.

But I need to avoid the red zone, I don't want to draw circles at 360°

Example below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let p be the center of the small circle, c the center of the main circle. Then a possible solution could look like

```
p.x = c.x + R * Cos(Fi)
p.y = c.y + R * Sin(Fi)
```

Here R is distance, Fi is angle in allowed interval (for example `-3*Pi/4..3*Pi/4`)